# VB6 - Convert Variant to Node

Tags: vb6, compiler-errors, type-conversion, nodes, variant

I am using a For Each loop to go through a Variant array in VB6. At one point, I want to convert the element of the loop (elem), which is a Variant, to a Node.

```
Dim elem as Variant

For Each elem In ndArray
    Dim nodle As Node
    nodle = CType(elem , Node)
Next
```

That's not the whole loop, but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. When I run this code, I get an error saying "Variable not defined", which points to the 'Node' in the CType method. This is not a variable, it is a type and the method should know that since it is expecting a type.

I tried skipping the CType method and just making nodle = elem, but I got an error saying "Object variable or With block variable not defined". I added the Set keyword in front of the expression and the error changed to "Object required"

When I debug and look at the elem variable, it appears to contain a valid Node value.

Anyone know what's going on here? Is this conversion even possible?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "CType method."  You can't just make stuff up and expect results.  Or is this a function that you wrote and failed to tell us about?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4x2877xb.aspx

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, your question is about VB6 but that link is for the confusingly-named VB.Net.  It doesn't apply to actual Visual Basic at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `Set`?

```
Set nodle = CType(elem , Node)
```

`Set` is necessary if `Node` is an object type and `nodle` will contain an object reference. If you omit `Set`, the compiler assumes that you want to change the default property of a `Node` object.

Comment: I changed my code to avoid having to convert elem at all. I no longer have the old code, so I can't test out your suggestion, sorry.